# ¿Cómo configuro postfix para que me permita el envío de forma externa a un buzón local que no existe?

Tags: servidor, postfix

Actualmente tengo dos servidores de corre uno local (Postfix) y uno remoto (Servicio de correos de una empresa X) como los buzones de correo remoto están limitados voy a utilizar mi servidor local para el envío de correos desde las aplicaciones locales (sendmail) pero el problema es cuando intento enviar por sendmail a un correo local este envia un error dado que la primera consulta es preguntarse el mismo si existe el correo respuesta que es "NO". Como puedo configurar para que este correo salga e intente resolver por fuera encontrando al servidor remoto que si cuenta con este buzón?.

Otra opción es crear este buzón en postfix pero entiendo que el mensaje no saldrá nunca porque el hará la entrega de forma local.

Comment: no seria mas facil migrar tu correo a una servidor en nube como por ejemplo `s2 amazon` y administrar  tu mismo el correo? hay mail servers opensource muy buenos como seria [zimbra](https://www.zimbra.com/downloads/) donde tendrias un 100% del control del espacio de los buzones sin pagar demaciado

Comment: Una da las cosas que me preocupa es el rechazo de los correos por parte de otros operadores como gmail, yahoo, outlook pues aunque hago todas las configuraciones muchas veces los correos terminan en spam. Por eso inicialmente opte por un tercero que administrara los correos, sin embargo estos servicios cobran por cada buzón y no permiten realizar relays. La opción que propones es una de los planes que tengo.